# comparing two files based on count and if the count differs it notifies via mail

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

am trying to compare two files in the same dir which for example is like a.txt,a1.txt, b.txt,b1.txt,c.txt,c1.txt. now I have a similar kind of multiple files. if there is going to be any change it has to mail me. I have written a sample code below but that errors out for me. If someone could help in correcting my mistake in the code or is there any other better way to approach the same.

```
for k in ls !*1.txt ;
do 
k1=$( wc -l < "$k" )
done
for i in ls *1.txt ;
do 
i1=$( wc -l < "$i" )
done
if [ "$k1" != "$i1" ];
then
grep -vf "$i" "$k" |  mail -s "hi" example@hifi.com ;
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't understand right, but try this

```
for ones in *1.txt
do
        diff "$ones" "${ones%1.txt}.txt"
done | mail -s 'changed files' example@hifi.com
```

for testing, omit the `| mail -s 'changed files' example@hifi.com`

Comment: I don't understand what does this `"${ones%1.txt}.txt"` do in `cmp "$ones" "${ones%1.txt}.txt"`. Could you explain

Comment: @user2970582 easiest explanation will see youself if you put `echo ` before cmp - so, instead execute will only show the cmp command... (see hhere too: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal )

Comment: ya i understand the logic now. But this code doesn't satisfy the logic am expecting

Comment: I f possible could you try helping me with my code itself and where it went wrong and so..

Comment: @user2970582 try formulate the question more precisely. The above script does what you said: it compares pairs of files like: `some.txt` and `some1.txt` and if they are different, will mail you the difference...

Comment: If the line count is different it would mail, and mail should consist the difference in content between the two text files

Comment: @user2970582 if want all difference - use `diff` - edited my answer.